# Calling getpass() says too many positional arguments when trying to print prompt

Tags: python

I am very new to Python (Only a couple weeks) and I'm trying to make a rock paper scissors game for Replits 100 days of code. My previous game was very simple and worked fine but it wont fly as a template for this lesson so I've started from scratch but I'm having trouble.

```
from getpass import getpass as hinput
ch1 = hinput("Enter",p1,"choice: ")
```

I keep getting this error after the players enter the names

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
    ch1 = hinput("Enter",p1,"choice: ")
TypeError: unix_getpass() takes from 0 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Comment: Your question should be about your specific technical problem, not your game as a whole, with a [mre] that's the **shortest possible program** that causes the same problem when run. I've edited towards that end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `getpass` like `print`. `print` is sort of special in Python, as it's written to take any number of arguments. You *can* write functions like that yourself, but it's not the default. And [`getpass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html) is written to only accept a single string as an argument (and an output stream, but we don't need that for our purposes).

You'll need to build the string yourself. That can be done with concatenation

```
hinput("Enter " + p1 + " choice: ")
```

or format strings

```
hinput("Enter %s choice: " % p1)       # Old (printf) style
hinput("Enter {} choice: ".format(p1)) # New style
```

or, on Python 3.5 and newer, f-strings

```
hinput(f"Enter {p1} choice: ")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```py
hinput(f"Enter {p1} choice: ")
```

This makes use of f-strings, which, for Python 3.5+, allow you to format variables within a string. For instance:

```
a = 4
b = 3
print(f"a + b = {a+b}")
>>> a + b = 7
```

Note that `"Enter",p1,"choice: "` is a tuple with 3 elements, and not a single string.